# MySQL: How to write the select statement in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, select, union-join

I want to get the following client's record when receiving 2 info: **province_id = 2002** and **staff_id = 9**

| client_id | client_name | province_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 336 | ebay | 2002 |

**Is it possible to make 1 select statement to get the result above?**

My current approach is VERY messy....

I am currently using a select statement to get a list of exclusive client_id

```
select staff_id, client_id from exclusive where exclusive.staff_id = 9;
```

then once I get the (exclusive list),

```
$result = array();
foreach(exclusiveList as aList) {
  client_id = aList['client_id'];
  $aClient = client->getClientDetail($client_id); // an array with client's info
  if(aClient['province_id'] == 2002) {
      array_push($result, aClient);
}
```

This is the table I have:

Division: Assigning a staff to handle client in some provinces

| staff_id | province_id |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 2001 |

Exclusive: Assigning a specific client to the Staff **outside** of their province

| staff_id | client_id |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 437 |
| 9 | 336 |

Client: All Clients

| client_id | client_name | province_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amazon | 2001 |
| 336 | ebay | 2002 |
| 437 | MarketPlace | 2047 |

Province

| province_id | province_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2001 | Alberta |
| 2002 | Ottawa |
| 2047 | Manitoba |

Thank you so much for your help, I have been working on this table for over a week before asking, as i have absolutely no clue on how to make it into one select statement.

Comment: This looks like a simple 2 table join so I'm a bit baffled by the question.

Comment: yes, it does look like a simple join at first, but i have no idea how to further filter the table base on province_id provided....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is bit unclear but it sounds like you only need a simple join:

```
select c.client_id, c.client_name, c.province_id
from division d
  join exclusive e on e.staff_id=d.staff_id
  join client c on e.client_id=c.client_id
where e.staff_id=9 and d.province_id=2002
```

Comment: Yes, base on statement above, this statement will get 2 client record, (client 437 & 336) but what about when user provide us with a province_id=2002? how can i further filter the result?

Comment: You can do that by adding the `division` to the join